# Send variable length vector with constant header in one message

Tags: c, mpi

I have n `workers`, 1 `master` (rank 0) and need to send messages via MPI from the n `workers` to the `master`. The message format is a variable length vector (`float *dta`) and constant size header `struct { int32_t x, int32_t y } dtaHdr`.

The master just loops through the incoming results and processes them. It is important for it to be able to associate which `dtaHdr`goes with which `dta`.

I know how to:

1. Create `MPI_Datatype` for the constant sized `dtaHdr` and send it via P2P `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv`.
2. Send a variable length vector of any datatype (e.g. `MPI_Float`) via P2P `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv`.

The issue is I have no idea how to combine these two approaches.

I know that I could:

- Send header first and then the data second in two separate messages.

  - That has the problem of reordering & interleaving of messages. I need a reliable, easy, and scalable way to associate the header and its data on `master`. With two messages I can't see a way how to always & simply get both a header and data for incoming message on the master. I.e. two `worker`s could send hdr & data messages to `master` & they could become interleaved. (I'm not sure what the guarantees for ordering are TBH, even after reading MPI specification).
- Encode both the header and the data to a `MPI_Byte` array and send it esseentially as a binary blob.

  - Sounds really dirty & breaks some guarantees.

**My question is**: how do I MPI-idiomatically send one identifiable logical message that contains both a constant sized header of one type and a variable sized vector of some second type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program uses `MPI_Pack` and `MPI_Unpack` to send two different types in the same message:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) \
    (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

struct data_header {
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
};

MPI_Datatype dt_header;
MPI_Datatype dt_vector;

void sendmsg(void) {
    struct data_header header = { 1, 2 };
    float example[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    char buffer[4096];
    int position;

    MPI_Pack(&header, 1, dt_header, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Pack(example, 1, dt_vector, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(buffer, position, MPI_PACKED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void recvmsg(void) {
    struct data_header header;
    float example[4];
    char buffer[4096];
    int position = 0;

    MPI_Recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer), MPI_PACKED, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Unpack(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &position, &header, 1, dt_header, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Unpack(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &position, example, 1, dt_vector, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", header.x, header.y);
    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE(example); index++) {
        printf("%f ", example[index]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int world_size;
    int world_rank;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_INT, &dt_header);
    MPI_Type_commit(&dt_header);
    MPI_Type_contiguous(4, MPI_FLOAT, &dt_vector);
    MPI_Type_commit(&dt_vector);

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        recvmsg();
    }
    else {
        sendmsg();
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
x = 1, y = 2
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
```

This is really just proof-of-concept code. Hopefully, it will help you find the solution you are looking for.

**Note**

This code does no error checking and should not be used in a production environment.

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I was looking for. Was thinking that there has to be a way to serialize message to a buffer.